# LASSO regression result different in Matlab and Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, machine-learning, mathematical-optimization

I am now trying to learn the ADMM algorithm (Boyd 2010) for LASSO regression.

I found out a very good example on this [page](http://www.simonlucey.com/lasso-using-admm/).

The matlab code is shown [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22893361/code/lasso_admm.m).

I tried to convert it into python language so that I could develop a better understanding.

Here is the code:

```
import scipy.io as io
import scipy.sparse as sp
import scipy.linalg as la
import numpy as np

def l1_norm(x):
    return np.sum(np.abs(x))

def l2_norm(x):
    return np.dot(x.ravel().T, x.ravel())

def fast_threshold(x, threshold):
    return np.multiply(np.sign(x), np.fmax(abs(x) - threshold, 0))

def lasso_admm(X, A, gamma):
    c = X.shape[1]
    r = A.shape[1]

    C = io.loadmat("C.mat")["C"]

    L = np.zeros(X.shape)

    rho = 1e-4
    maxIter = 200
    I = sp.eye(r)
    maxRho = 5

    cost = []

    for n in range(maxIter):
        B = la.solve(np.dot(A.T, A) + rho * I, np.dot(A.T, X) + rho * C - L)

        C = fast_threshold(B + L / rho, gamma / rho)

        L = L + rho * (B - C);  

        rho = min(maxRho, rho * 1.1); 

        cost.append(0.5 * l2_norm(X - np.dot(A, B)) + gamma * l1_norm(B))

    cost = np.array(cost).ravel()

    return B, cost

data = io.loadmat("lasso.mat")
A = data["A"]
X = data["X"]    
B, cost = lasso_admm(X, A, gamma)
```

I have found the loss function did not converge after 100+ iterations. Matrix B did not tend to be sparse, on the other hand, the matlab code worked in different situations.

I have checked with different input data and compared with Matlab outputs, yet I still could not get hints.

Could anybody take a try?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please make this question better by including a *complete* example, especially including what values of X, A and gamma you passed to your function. You say that you used various, but provide at least one set, so that others can quickly check your code. (-1 wasn't  from me)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I used two input files to test above code. See [C.mat] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/g0vb3s3cib614pm/C.mat?dl=0) and [lasso.mat] (https://www.dropbox.com/s/57ia207tjzp4ic6/lasso.mat?dl=0). Note that this version is a little bit different from the original Matlab code for the latter one uses random matrix.

Answer (score 1):

My gut feeling as to why this is not working to your expectations is your `la.solve()` call.  `la.solve()` assumes that the matrix is full rank and is independent (i.e. invertible).  When you use `\` in MATLAB, what MATLAB does under the hood is that if the matrix is full rank, the exact inverse is found.  However, should the matrix not be this way (i.e. overdetermined or underdetermined), the solution to the system is solved by least-squares instead.  I would suggest you modify that call so that you're using [`lstsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) instead of `solve`.  As such, simply replace your `la.solve()` call with this:

```
sol = la.lstsq(np.dot(A.T, A) + rho * I, np.dot(A.T, X) + rho * C - L)
B = sol[0]
```

Note that `lstsq` returns a whole bunch of outputs in a 4-element tuple, in addition to the solution.  The solution of the system is in the first element of this tuple, which is why I did `B = sol[0]`.  What is also returned are the sums of residues (second element), the rank (third element) and the singular values of the matrix you are trying to invert when solving (fourth element).

---

Also some peculiarities that I have noticed:

- One thing that may or may not matter is the random generation of numbers. MATLAB and Python NumPy generate random numbers differently, so this may or may not affect your solution.
- In MATLAB, Simon Lucey's code initializes `L` to be a zero matrix such that `L = zeros(size(X));`.  However, in your Python code, you initialize `L` to be this way: `L = np.zeros(C.shape);`. You are using different variables to ascertain the shape of `L`.  Obviously, the 
  code wouldn't work if there was a dimension mismatch, but that's another thing that's different.  Not sure if this will affect your solution either.

---

So far I haven't found anything out of the ordinary, so try that fix and let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your keen help. 1. I have tried to use lstsq yet it generates the same results as solve did before. 2. My friend helped me to modify the python code, as now it takes certain input data (see above comment for links). I can see the loss function begins to diverge after 114 iteration times. My point is that the random assignment does not seem to be a problem in this case. 3. I have modified the L size in above code.

Comment: @SpencerLo - What happened? Did what I suggest work?